# want to change csv file date column format

Tags: unix, awk

Im newbie to batch/shell scripting. I have a CSV file like this:

```
Id  depId   Name    city    Date                    prod
12345   52845   ken LA  08.08.2013 16:06:53 KLS22
25685   28725   Larry   MA  09.03.2013 16:06:58 KLt35
58345   28545   ken LA  06.08.2013 16:06:53 KLS22
75885   98725   Gow CA  05.04.2013 16:06:58 KLt35
```

about 2000 records. col are delimited by tab. I would like to change the date column to the format:

```
DD_MM_YYY_hh_mm_ss
```

I have tried something like this with awk:

```
awk -F '' '{ ("date -d \""$5"\" \"+%Y:%m/%d %T\"") | getline $5; print }' myfile.csv
```

but i get wrong output.

I expect output like this:

```
Id  depId   Name    city    Date                    prod
58345   28545   ken LA  03_06_2013_23_00_00 KLS22
75885   98725   Gow CA  05_06_2013_23_00_00 KLt35
```

Please help out! Thanks!!

Comment: Putty is where i run the unix command

Comment: That is totally irrelevant for the question. And your command runs inside a shell on the unix style system accessed by a ssh session, not "in putty" ;-)

Comment: csv file with no `,`??

Comment: Don't tell us you've got wrong output. We don't see it. You do. You have to tell us _what_ output you are getting and _what_ you expected.

Comment: You still didn't tell us what output you are _getting_.

Comment: `8.8.2013 16:06:53` is not a valid date, so `date -d "8.8.2013 16:06:53"` will give error.

Comment: wanted the date to include timestamp

Answer (score 1):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{gsub(/\./,"_",$5);gsub(/:/,"_",$6);$5=$5"_"$6;$6=$NF;NF--}{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" myfile.csv
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat temp
Id  depId   Name    city    Date                    prod
12345   52845   ken LA  8.8.2013 16:06:53   KLS22
25685   28725   Larry   MA  9.3.2013 16:06:58   KLt35
58345   28545   ken LA  6.8.2013 16:06:53   KLS22
75885   98725   Gow CA  5.4.2013 16:06:58   KLt35

$ awk 'NR>1{gsub(/\./,"_",$5);gsub(/:/,"_",$6);$5=$5"_"$6;$6=$NF;NF--}{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" temp
Id      depId   Name    city    Date    prod
12345   52845   ken     LA      8_8_2013_16_06_53       KLS22
25685   28725   Larry   MA      9_3_2013_16_06_58       KLt35
58345   28545   ken     LA      6_8_2013_16_06_53       KLS22
75885   98725   Gow     CA      5_4_2013_16_06_58       KLt35
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach which does not check if the string that looks like the date is really in the right columnt:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\t(\d)\.(\d)\.(\d\d\d\d) /sprintf("\t%04d-%02d-%02d ", $3, $2, $1) /e' t.csv
12345   52845   ken     LA      2013-08-08 16:06:53     KLS22
25685   28725   Larry   MA      2013-03-09 16:06:58     KLt35
```